# TableView isn't showing fetched data from the database

Tags: java, javafx, ravendb

I'm developing a small application for personal use using javafx on the front end. However, I'm facing this problem: Data fetched from the database is not displayed in the TableView.
I am using RavenDB 3.5 as my database.

My controller class:

```
public class FXMLHomePageController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private VBox vBox;
    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;
    @FXML
    private Tab tabFornecedores, tabGraficos;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPaneFornecedores;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Fornecedor> tableFornecedores;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fornecedor, String> colIdFornecedor;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fornecedor, String> colNomeFantasia;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fornecedor, String> colCnpjFornecedor;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Fornecedor, String> colEmailFornecedor;
    @FXML
    private Button btNovoFornecedor;
    @FXML
    private Button btDetalhesFornecedor;
    @FXML
    private Button btEditarFornecedor;
    @FXML
    private Button btRemoverFornecedor;

    private FornecedorDAO dao = new FornecedorDAO();

    private ObservableList<Fornecedor> fornecedores = FXCollections.observableArrayList(dao.getAll());

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        colIdFornecedor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Fornecedor, String>("id"));
        colNomeFantasia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Fornecedor, String>("nomeFantasia"));
        colCnpjFornecedor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Fornecedor, String>("cnpj"));
        colEmailFornecedor.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Fornecedor, String>("email"));

        tableFornecedores.getItems().addAll(fornecedores);
    }

}
```

My FXML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:id="vBox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children>
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" prefHeight="606.0" prefWidth="800.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
    <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="tabFornecedores" text="Fornecedores">
           <content>
              <AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPaneFornecedores" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                 <children>
                    <TableView fx:id="tableFornecedores" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="79.0" prefHeight="431.0" prefWidth="744.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="61.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="28.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="28.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="79.0">
                      <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colIdFornecedor" prefWidth="75.0" text="#" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="colNomeFantasia" prefWidth="153.0" text="Nome Fantasia" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="colCnpjFornecedor" prefWidth="251.0" text="CNPJ" />
                          <TableColumn fx:id="colEmailFornecedor" prefWidth="264.0" text="E-mail" />
                      </columns>
                    </TableView>
                    <Button fx:id="btNovoFornecedor" layoutX="622.0" layoutY="21.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="150.0" text="Novo Fornecedor" />
                    <Button fx:id="btDetalhesFornecedor" layoutX="28.0" layoutY="523.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Detalhes do Fornecedor" />
                    <Button fx:id="btEditarFornecedor" layoutX="228.0" layoutY="523.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Editar Fornecedor" />
                    <Button fx:id="btRemoverFornecedor" layoutX="429.0" layoutY="523.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="160.0" text="Remover Fornecedor" />
                 </children>
              </AnchorPane>
           </content>
        </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="tabGraficos" text="Gráficos" />
    </tabs>
  </TabPane>
  </children>
 </VBox>
```

My DAO file:

```
public class FornecedorDAO {

    private IDocumentStore store;
    private IDocumentSession session;

    public FornecedorDAO() {
        store = DatabaseConnection.openConnection();
        session = store.openSession("easystock");
    }

    public void save(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
        session.store(fornecedor);
        session.saveChanges();
    }

    public void update(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
        Fornecedor oldForn = session.load(Fornecedor.class, fornecedor.getId());
        oldForn.setNomeFantasia(fornecedor.getNomeFantasia());
        oldForn.setCnpj(fornecedor.getCnpj());
        oldForn.setEmail(fornecedor.getEmail());
        oldForn.setEndereco(fornecedor.getEndereco());
        oldForn.setProdutosFornecidos(fornecedor.getProdutosFornecidos());
        session.saveChanges();

    }

    public void remove(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
        session.delete(fornecedor.getId());
        session.saveChanges();
    }

    public List<Fornecedor> getAll() {
        return session.query(Fornecedor.class).take(Integer.MAX_VALUE).toList();
    }

    public List<Fornecedor> getByName(String name) {
        QFornecedor query = QFornecedor.fornecedor;
        return session.query(Fornecedor.class)
                .where(query.nomeFantasia.contains(name))
                .toList();
    }

}
```

POJO Class:

```
@QueryEntity
public class Fornecedor {

private String id;
private String nomeFantasia;
private String cnpj;
private String email;
private Endereco endereco;
private List<Produto> produtosFornecidos;

// getters & setters
}
```

Application class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/HomePage.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Have you confirmed there is something in the list that is returned from the DAO? 2. Can you [edit] the question to include the `Fornecedor` class?

Comment: Also, there is no `fx:controller` attribute in the FXML file. Are you setting the controller in code? Can you show the `Application` class?

Comment: 1. Yes, i did. I already edit question. About the controller, I was editing the file and I ended up removing the attribute. I added it again!

Comment: So with the added `fx:controller` attribute, does that make it work?

Comment: Yep, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your FXML file is missing the `fx:controller` attribute. You need:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox fx:controller="my.package.FXMLHomePageController" fx:id="vBox" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <!-- ... -->

</VBox>
```

where `my.package` is the name of the package containing the `FXMLHomePageController` class.